# identityServer con parámetro adicional para obtener token

Tags: identity

Tengo que agregar un parámetro para la obtención del token en identityserver4. user, pass y cuit, hice un ResourceOwnerPasswordValidationContext , funciona bien desde postman, pero desde un cliente de .net core 3.1 el parámetro CUIT no llega, alguna idea de como puedo hacer para que el cliente le envié ese parámetro ? ya herede y especialice

pero cuando lo envio al servidor no llega el parámetro cuit adjunto imagenes del server y del cliente

Agradezco ayuda u otro enfoque de como obtener el token con user, pass y cuit. desde ya muchisimas gracias

Codigo del cliente que tilizo para pedir el token por usario, password y Cuit

```
            //HttpContent httpC
            var identityServerResponse = await httpClient.RequestPasswordTokenAsync(new PasswordRequestTokenCustom
            {
                Address = "http://localhost:5000/connect/token",
                //Address = "https://dev-iudu-apim.azure-api.net/auth/connect/token",
                ClientId = "mobile_client",
                ClientSecret = "secret_mobile",
                Scope = "customers",
                UserName = "user3",
                Password = "123456",//.Sha265() 
                cuit = "22222222",
                
            });
```

Codigo de override en el identity Server
para ello extendi el metodo de la clase

public class CustomResourceOwnerPasswordValidator : IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator

public Task ValidateAsync(ResourceOwnerPasswordValidationContext context)
{
//context.Request.ClientClaims

```
        string cuit = string.Empty;

        if (context.Request.Raw["cuit"] != null)
        {
            cuit = context.Request.Raw["cuit"].ToString();
        }
        else
            cuit = "22222222";

        if (_repository.ValidatePassword(context.UserName, context.Password, cuit))
        {
            context.Result = new GrantValidationResult(_repository.GetUserByUsername(context.UserName).Id.ToString(), "password", null, "local", null);
            return Task.FromResult(context.Result);
        }
        context.Result = new GrantValidationResult(TokenRequestErrors.InvalidGrant, "El usuario y el password no son correctos", null);
        return Task.FromResult(context.Result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Encontre la solucion, cambie la llamada del client por httpclient directa y pude resolver la llamada con el parametro cuit

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo resolvi, cambie la forma en la que llamo al server desde el cliente.[image: Codigo funcionando]